# What is bad with my questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

Sometimes I am getting downvotes for my questions and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong, please? I would like to improve, but how can I do that?

**Examples:** (both have 2 downvotes):

[The application runs in the debugger mode, the debugger won't connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113193/the-application-wont-stop-on-breakpoints-in-debug-mode)

[Why does LinearLayout instance.getLayoutParams look to have a wrong class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942415/why-linearlayout-instance-getlayoutparams-looks-to-have-a-wrong-class)

Comment: Please stop adding "beforehand grateful" to all your questions.  It really isn't necessary.  Let your upvotes and selected answers be your thanks.

Comment: ["*As I see from my marks, nobody likes difficult questions :-)*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113193/the-application-wont-stop-on-breakpoints-in-debug-mode) You'd  do better if you avoided insulting folks, even when accompanied with a smiley.

Comment: @Won't Is it punishable?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta. My reaction was put there after these two minuses. If, according to Won't, upvotes are thanks, than what are downvotes? Expressions of dislike, of course. For what?

Comment: Upvotes on questions are **not** thanks (Won't is talking about answers), and downvotes are **not** expressions of dislike. Mouse over the upvote and downvote arrows to see what they actually are. That said, we're human here, most of us, and you've got to expect insults to be met in kind.

Comment: If the question is unclear, wouldn't it be reasonable to put some comment about what is unclear? I gave every bit of info that I thought could be useful. What could I do else, not knowing what is the matter?  BTW, if you look into the first question now, you'll se, that I have found the answer, that is never met here or, pardon me, I haven't found a mention on it on the net, too. How could I know?

Comment: That is the problem I am afraid: When a question is really far from the usual ones, it is much harder to formulate in usual way and as a result the author is punished. On the contrary, hundreds of almost same questions are hunted upon to answer immediately and answerer and questioner get heaps of pluses really breaking the rules and the very sense of this server. Think: do we need really new questions? How could they be clearly formulated for the answerer if they are really new? Should the questioners be punished for them?

Comment: @Gangnus: No, absolutely not.  Its just not needed.  Some users will end up flagging you if you keep adding salutations, taglines, or "thanks" to all your posts.  Others will edit them out.  Its just our ethos here.  Keep your posts neat, tidy and to the point.  We have some users who absolutely refuse not to comply, even after being asked repeatedly.  Its at that point that it becomes disruptive, and disruption *is* something that is "punishable."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first question you link to you are asking for help debugging your code, but you don't show any of that code. How are people supposed to help if they can't see your code?

That would get you a down vote from me. If you show code, I, for one, am much less likely to down vote.

Comment: The application has about 8 activities and 15 different xml files. The application didn't changed since the times when it allowed to be debugged. What I had to publish? All 2000 lines? When I publish questions with longer code (50 lines, not 2000), simply nobody reads them.

Comment: You have done the right thing by asking for advice on how to improve your questions, don't turn it into an argument. My answer was advice on why I would down vote your question and a number of people seem to agree. It makes no difference wether you think it's right or not, that is the way SO works. There is good advice on writing good questions [here](http://www.allthingsnow.com/day/coding/shared/6519529/Writing-the-perfect-question-Jon-Skeet-Coding-Blog), I would suggest you read it.

Comment: Thank you, it surely will be useful. I am not arguing, sorry, i am asking what I have to do in such situation. Would be enough to say *why* I am not supplying the code?

Comment: Possibly, but even a simplified, cut down version of your code that illustrates your problem is better than none. People on SO like code :)

Comment: @Gangnus: Your best bet, when you have a problem, is to create a ["Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"](http://sscce.org/) which reproduces your problem.  Usually that will reveal the solution without having to ask anybody else.  And, if not, you can use *that code* in your question.

Comment: @Won't Ahem, the problem was that *that* application won't debug. On two different IDE. Others debugged ok. Comrad, how many questioners have you seen here that took the work to test the problem on two IDEs? I have not seen here much more prepaired questions than that mine. I have worked 4 hours for not to ask some rubbish. And it really was a problem new for this server and dangerous for future developers. I am not waiting for gratitude, but to be punished for it... Hmm it is the same real world as usually. It was foolish of me to ask about it.